# How to send push notification using socketio to a android device when it will return online

Tags: socket.io, rabbitmq, mqtt, publish-subscribe, instant-messaging

I have spent lot of times researching about instant messaging (as well as notification) between different platforms (android, ios app, web app).

I have figured out the main concept (I can be wrong though. Please correct me if I wrong). That is, I need:

1. A webserver (say, it is comprised of **nodejs+express+socketio**)
2. Some clients those will be connected to the server via socketio-client (android can be also a client)
3. A message broker (rabbitmq or redis or mqtt) can also be used to temporarily store the incoming messages on it and send it to its destination user after saving it on database

**The main problem is now with offline push notification. Suppose a web client send a message to an android client and the android is now offline. When the device will return online then how to push a notification to it about it's pending message.**

Answer (score 0):

With MQTT 'Publish' packets, you can set a 'Retain' flag such that when your Android device(s) get connected, and they Subscribe to the published Topic, they will be sent the last retained MQTT packet for that Topic.

So if all you need is the last message sent, this should work fine for you.  If your devices need ALL messages sent since it was last online, then you will need a different mechanism.

Comment: Such as a higher QOS value and a persistent connection so the broker will queue messages for you.

Comment: The 'Retain' flag is set by the Publisher nodes....so what language is/are it/they using?